# iOS pause and resume Location Manager

Tags: ios, xcode

In my app I want to track user movement for every second. I can track user movement. Now I want to pause the location manager for couple of minutes and resume the location manager again after sometime.
How can I do this?

Comment: You could use a timer and the methods startUpdatingLocation & stopUpdatingLocation of the location manager.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm sound like you are not using CoreLocation properly. Instead of tracking user movement every second you could just call 
[- startUpdatingLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startUpdatingLocation) and listen for updates in 
[- locationManager:didUpdateLocations:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didUpdateLocations:). The system will take care of the rest.

In order to stop listening just call [- stopUpdatingLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/stopUpdatingLocation) and trigger `startUpdatingLocation` with `dispatch_after` or something like this.

You may also find helpful [- startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges)